# What does a Vector3 state?

Tags: unity, vector

I'm really stucked. I couldn't understand what does `Vector3` state.

When I look Unity Vector3 documentation it says

> Representation of 3D vectors and points.

According to this sentence, a `Vector3` can state a point or a vector in space.

But When I go into other documentation about `Vector3` it really confused me.

For example When I look `Vector3 Constructor` documentation it says

> Creates a new vector with given x, y, z components.

So that means `Vector3` states a vector.

But When I look `Debug.DrawLine(Vector3 startpoint, Vector3 endpoint)`
it says startpoint and lookpoint are points in world space.
So according to this, Vector3 is a point not a vector

I can increase the examples.

For example when I go into `transform.position` documentation it says,

> The world space position of the Transform.

So it says Vector3 is a position(that means point. I think you can't state a position with Vector)

But when we try to change a position of gameobject with `transform.position` we again use `Vector3`
and that state a vector.Because you can't change position of a gameobject with point. You could use Vector

So, what does a `Vector3` state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Vector3` is a set of 3 float values: x, y, and z. These 3 values can represent whatever you want, but usually are used to represent the three axes of either a **position**, a **vector**, or a **euler rotation**.

You generally should be able to tell what a `Vector3` represents from context/variable naming. It's important to make the context clear, to avoid mistakes like this:

```
Vector3 a = transform.position;
Vector3 b = transform.eulerAngles;
a += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
b += rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
//oops, we mixed these up! we should have used better variable names!
transform.position = b;
transform.eulerAngles = a;
```

Your question is analogous to asking "what does a float represent"? A float simply stores a floating-point value; it isn't inherently a distance or a speed or a time or a weight or any other specific type of unit. The meaning of the value is taken from context, e.g.

```
float distance = Vector3.Distance(point1, point2);
float time = Time.time;
float speed = 5.5;
```

Comment: Okay I think I got it.  Basically What you saying is Vector3 is just three float value. But how come three float value can represent a Vector ? Don't we need at least two point in space to make a Vector ? andhHow can I learn which method represent position, vector or euler rotation ?

Comment: A vector is formally defined as a quantity having direction and magnitude. That definition does not require defining specific start or end points. As I said in the answer, you should be able to determine how the Vector3 is being used from context.

Comment: For example, if we have a point A at (2,2,2) and a point B at (3,3,3), the vector from A to B is (1,1,1). If we have point C at (5,5,5) and point D at (6,6,6) the vector from C to D is also (1,1,1). Those are distance vectors, but the specific start and end points aren't part of the definition. We can also define other quantities, such as velocity, using vectors.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now I understood

Comment: You can think of vector as a point offset away from 0,0,0 then you take that "line" and move it to start from whatever initial point you like. In other words vector is a point away from wherever you choose to begin to "count".